# How to display Yoast SEO meta description in archive template for each post instead of the_excerpt()?

Tags: loop, post-meta, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I read this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89782/display-yoast-wordpress-seo-title-in-archive-template) but it wasn't what I was looking for exactly. I'm new to Wordpress and a little confuse with the functions and everything.

How can I get the metadescription in the loop for each post?

Thanks !

Comment: In what way was it not what you were looking for exactly?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add the following code in the archive template loop to display Yoast SEO meta description for each post.

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true);
```