# How to display custom seo title before the loop?

Tags: php, filters, title, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

So I've optimized one of my archive page title to this

```
       add_filter('wpseo_title', 'new_filter_title');

      function new_filter_title($title)

      {
        if ( is_page('1637') && $id = get_queried_object_id() )
        {

          $locations = get_query_var('area');
          $location = get_term_by('slug', $locations, 'area');
          $models = get_query_var('serie');
          $model = get_term_by('slug', $models, 'serie');

          $title = '';

          if($model && $model) $title .= $model->name . ' Used';
          else $title .= 'Used';

          $title .= ' Cars For Sale';

          if($location && $location) $title .= ' In ' . $location->name;

          $title .= ' on ' . get_bloginfo('name');



          return $title;
        }

        return $title;
      }
```

and this works perfectly. So what I'm trying to do now is echo the same title in the page before the loop. how do I this?

I've already tried this solution

`echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);`

That didn't work. it instead returned variables `%%title%% ........%%sitename%%`

Comment: i help you try this code

Comment: $titles = get_option( 'wpseo_titles' );
$title  = $titles['title-ptarchive-POST_TYPE'];

echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $title );

Comment: To display all the wpseo_title variables, you can use:

printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( get_option( 'wpseo_titles' ), 1 ) );

Comment: function yoastVariableToTitle($post_id) {
    $yoast_title = get_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);
    $title = strstr($yoast_title, '%%', true);
    if (empty($title)) {
        $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    }
    return $title;
}

Comment: Thanks man! I tried your code. The first one still displays variables like this `%%pt_plural%% Archive %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%` . the second one does exactly as it should, it displays all wpseo titles, it helped me alot for something else. the third one does not show anything at all.

Comment: your problem solve or not

Comment: I've edited my code above to show all of it. It works just fine on the `wpseo_title` . I just want to show it exactly as it is on the page as H1 title

Comment: No. its not solved yet

Comment: please check url : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89782/display-yoast-wordpress-seo-title-in-archive-template